# Blue flashing light

Tags: honda, warning-light

My 2017 Honda HR-V has a blue flashing light on the arm of the rearview mirror. It started flashing after I locked and left the car tonight. Why? Is this going to run the battery down?

Answer (score 1):

I found people asking the same question on a few different sites, these are the answers they came up with:

- It's a power indicator for a dashcam.
- It's an indicator that the alarm is active.
- It's a light sensor that the car uses to dim the reflections in the rear view mirror when driving in the dark.